# Using distinct and case for two separate columns

Tags: sql, count, distinct, case

I am counting cases by year using the following code:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Year(FilingDate)=2008 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '2008'
```

and I want to only count these cases when another column is distinct.  The other column is called 'FilingDate'  What I imagine would look something like this:

```
COUNT(CASE distinct (DocketNumber) WHEN Year(FilingDate)=2008 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '2008',
```

The Sample Records:

DocketNumber FilingDate

123   2008

123   2008

123   2008

111   2009

112   2009

I would just like to recieve = 1
Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can you give sampl records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option with [SUBQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN YearFilingDate = 2008 THEN 1 END) AS '2008'
FROM
 (      
  SELECT Year(FilingDate) AS YearFilingDate, DocketNumber
  FROM dbo.test55
  GROUP BY Year(FilingDate), DocketNumber
  ) x
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08879/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Year(FilingDate)=2008 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS '2008'
GROUP BY DocketNumber
```

may be.